# Load external requirejs module into own application

Tags: requirejs

I have a large requirejs App. Now I have an external library that comes as a bunch of requireJs modules. My first idea was to compile the modules into a single file an require only this module. But this seems not to work. The compiled module looks like this

**lib.js**

```
define("a", function(){

})


define("b", function(){

})


define("", function(){

})
```

in my module I load it like this

```
define(['lib'], function(){
})
```

Comment: maybe leave them separate during development and save the combining for the r.js optimizer later?

Comment: There are some problems with that in my setup but maybe thats the right way to go.

Comment: Can you import a compiled module in that way, or do you simply need to include `lib.js` as a separate script?